# Rails - seeding with paperclip images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, seed

I found several questions on that topic and I followed the instructions to seed my models with images. However, when seeding I get an error "PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column meals.meal_avatar does not exist" even though my model has it. This is my Meal model

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :meal_avatar, styles: { large: '300x300' }, default_url: '/images/:style/missing.png'
  validates_attachment_content_type :meal_avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

This is the migration

```
  def self.up
    change_table :meals do |t|
      t.attachment :meal_avatar
    end
  end
```

The allowed parameters in the controller

```
  def meal_params
    params.require(:meal).permit(:name, :meal_avatar)
  end
```

The way I seed the image(It is out of context but you can get the idea)

```
meal_seed = [
  {
    name: "Salad",
    meal_avatar: File.new("app/assets/images/salad.jpg")
  }
]
meal_seed.each do |meal_params|
  meal = category.meals.find_or_create_by(meal_params)
end
```

Any idea why my seeds fail :? Thank you!

Comment: Not 100% sure but i think it could be the path you supplied is incorrect. Try: `meal_avatar: File.new(Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "salad.jpg"))`

Comment: Didn't work. Getting the same error. Thank you, though :)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The same as before
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column meals.meal_avatar does not exist

Comment: What does the table look like?

Comment: `#  id                       :integer          not null, primary key
#  name                     :string
#  created_at               :datetime         not null
#  updated_at               :datetime         not null
#  category_id              :integer
#  meal_avatar_file_name    :string
#  meal_avatar_content_type :string
#  meal_avatar_file_size    :integer
#  meal_avatar_updated_at   :datetime`

Comment: Try restarting the server? Also, where do you use `meal_seed` (you have `find_or_create_by(meal_params)`)?

Comment: I edited the code provided in the question. Also, I seed by resetting the database: rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with `find_or_create_by`. I believe the find happens before the paperclip object has been processed, which is why its trying to look for the column `meal_avatar`.

Separate them out into two lines.

```
meal_seed.each do |meal_params|
  avatar = meal_params.delete(:meal_avatar)
  meal = category.meals.find_or_initialize_by(meal_params)
  meal.meal_avatar = avatar

  meal.save
end
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this it may be work for you!

```
meal_seed.each_with_index do |meal_params, index|
  Meal.create!(meal_params)  
end
```